# Snapd snap-confine circular dependency

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, snap

I can't install libgmp because it seems like snap-confine and snapd have a circular dependency.
How do i deal with this?

```
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snap-confine:
 snap-confine depends on snapd (= 2.23~14.04); however:
  Package snapd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snap-confine (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
 snap-confine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Could you please file a bug about this? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+filebug